# Misalignment when using tagging package in tables

Tags: tables, alignment

when using the [tagging package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tagging) in a table I always get misalignment in some rows. It seems like "unused" tags create some whitespace which is then added at the beginning of the next row.

**Example**

When using `firsttag` everything is fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagging}
\usetag{firsttag}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & b\\
\tagged{firsttag}{c & d\\}
\tagged{secondtag}{e & f\\}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: working example]

When using `secondtag` there is some whitespace in front of the second row which causes misalignment:

```latex
...
\usetag{secondtag}
...
```

[image]

Is there any way to align the rows correctly even when having some unused tags in a table?

The [source code of the tagging package](https://github.com/Hightor/tagging/blob/master/tagging.sty) does not seem to be too complex. But I'm new to latex and have hard times understanding how it works internally. Unfortunately, the original author is deceased. That's why I'm asking here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the space between both tags with a `%`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagging}
%\usetag{firsttag}
\usetag{secondtag}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & b\\
\tagged{firsttag}{c & d\\}%
\tagged{secondtag}{e & f\\}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was actually pretty easy solution.